# Fine tune MariaDB to local development

Tags: mariadb

How can I fine tune MariaDB for local work in my computer?
I use a LAMP server in Virtualbox my computer, for web design local development (only me).
The problem is I find the MariaDB slow. For example, sometimes it takes about 10 seconds to edit some Wordpress pages in it's Dashboard. I understand that a database server like MAriaDB is configured by default to handle the workload of many simultaneous connections. So, it must impose limits to them.
But, in this case, as there is only one person, I would like to lift all those limits and unleash the full power of it, so operations that take now 10 seconds can be done in 1 second or less.
So, what changes can I make in order to accomplish this? I have googled and made various changes to mariadb-server.cnf, but only accomplished litle speed. I use some tools to measure performance, and they all give me ultrafast PHP performance, but slow database one.
Also, it's not mandatory for me to use MariaDB; I can stop using it and use other solution more adequate to this situation. Can somebody shed some light in here?

Comment: should more like a DNS resolution error - `skip-name-resolve` as a MariadB setting.

Comment: @danblack: that is already set

Comment: are you out of memory in the VM and have allocated much memory to mariadb. Is it swapping (vmstat 5 ; look at si/so)? A basic unconfigured database should handle a local WordPress site ok. Try the minimal settings and then tune based on observed need. Are table MyISAM or Innodb (use innodb in preparation for multi user)

Comment: @danblack: I thank you for helping me. Well, I'm using an i5 processor 4th generation, giving half the processors to the virtual machine and half of my 8 GB RAM . Also, I have monitored it with top and memory and cpu were always bellow 20%. So, I guess that it's not a question of specs. Also, the front end of the website loads very fast, almost instantaneous. The problem is the wordpress admin dashboard.

Comment: So, I google about it (wordpress slow dashboard) and it seems many people have the same problem, because there are many articles on this subject. So, I guess this is not a problem of my lamp server or hardware, although I understand that a more powerful machine would of course be faster. https://www.google.pt/search?q=wordpress+dashboard+slow&ei=kJ-5X9GUAd6SjLsP0cWA-AY&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjRnO2X4pTtAhVeCWMBHdEiAG8Q8NMDegQIDhBR&biw=1423&bih=949